# how to set calendar in date field filter of Microsoft Report Builder of TFS 2013?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, alm, tfs-reports

How can add "calendar" as parameter of date field (activated date, closed date, changed date etc.) in TFS report?

i am using MS SSRS to prepare report from analysis database of TFS. only select table & Parameter but cannot add calendar in parameter to filter the report.

how can i add this??

Answer (score 1):

1 In design view right click on the date parameter you have created (you can also double click on the parameter) That will open up the Report Parameter Properties

2 Under General on the data type drop down. Select the text and choose Date/Dime
That will do it. If you preview your report  the calendar will be there

Comment: shows error. "<Default Value 1>  value is not a date or time"

Comment: @Abdul Ahad. Can you explain exactly what you want to do and the parameter data type of the field

Comment: i am trying to prepare report using microsoft report designer from tfs_analysis database. i have created report using drag & drop from analysis database defined tables. where some  default date field exist such as created date, activated date, start date, finish date. i want to add calendar in date filter. i think u can undestand my problem. can u share your mail address then i can send u some image.